# provide pool, virtual disc and shares

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

I am beginning to learn PowerShell on my own. In one of the books (Windows Server 2012 R2, implementation and maintaning) I got the task where I have to create script which after run, will create a storage pool, virtual disc, and new shares on new created vdisc.

Based on book instruction this is what I did already:

```
New-StoragePool -FriendlyName "Pool" -StorageSubSystemFriendlyName (Get-StorageSubSystem).FriendlyName -PhysicalDisk (Get-PhysicalDisk | where CanPool -eq True) -ProvisingTypeDefault Thin -ResiliencySettingNameDefault Mirror

New-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "vDisk1" -StoragePoolFriendlyName "Pool" -Size 5TB

New-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "vDisk2" -StoragePoolFriendlyName "Pool" -Size 10TB

New Partition -DiskNumber(Get-Disk | where BusType -eq Spaces).Number -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -Confirm:$false
```

Now I want to create shared folders for newly created virtual disk by `New-Item` Function. The problem is that I am not sure how to create a path for multiple disks and what's more the parameter `-AssignDriveLetter` from `New Partition` creates drive letter automatically. Because of that I do not know the drive letters. As a result I do not know how to set up variable `Path` in `New-Item`.

Comment: This is for Hyper-V?

Comment: Hi , yes server is on Hyper-V

Comment: On hyper v i set up 2 physicall disc (which are offline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a general approach with this:
Use variables as you configure your pools and disks, so you can reuse the them in your next steps and there will be references to specific objects that you have created:

```
$NewPartitions = New-Partition -DiskNumber(Get-Disk | where BusType -eq Spaces).Number -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -Confirm:$false
```

`$NewPartitions` variable will contain an array of your new partitions along with their drive letters, which you can iterate with `foreach` loop executing `New-Item` each time:

```
$NewFolders = foreach ($DriveLetter in ($NewPartitions.DriveLetter))
 {
  New-Item -Type Directory -Path ($DriveLetter+":\share")
 }
```

This will yield a folder called "share" on each of the drives, which you might want to then pass to `New-SmbShare` cmdlet using the same tactics. `$NewFolders.FullName` contains full paths of your newly created folders.